# Why cant i find site_perl directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, perl

I am compiling a program from source code. It requires path to my site_perl directory. When I run perl -V, i see that there is /usr/local/lib/site_perl at the end but i cant find the directory in the path. So, I am confused what path to provide for site_perl. Can anyone help me or direct me to related reading?

```
$perl -V
...........
  @INC:
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.14
/usr/share/perl/5.14
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
```

Thanks!!

Comment: AFAIK that's just a list of possible include paths - it's not a list of things that definitely exist.

Comment: So, which path should I give for site_perl? I receive segmentation fault when I run the program I installed and I am afraid that because of site_perl path

Comment: What is the program you are trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

$ oldperl -S pmpath CGI CGI::Imagemap

This should output the location of the Imagemap module, which should be in pm_perl/CGI/ if it exists.